# are "clothes of a particular type" & "a particular type of clothes" the same?

Tags: meaning

Now, are "to wear clothes of a particular type**" & 
"to wear a particular type of clothes**" the same?

> When is it appropriate to wear clothes of a particular type?

and

> When is it appropriate to wear a particular type of clothes?

Comment: Either is fine. And they mean the same thing.

Comment: Note that it you're missing a some words in your example sentences; they should be something like: _When is **it appropriate** to wear ..._

Comment: In practice I suspect *When is it appropriate to wear particular **types** of clothes?* might be more common for the second construction. But they're all fine, and all mean the same.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same thing, but they have different emotional weight.

If I said I was going to wear a particular type of clothes then I might be wearing casual clothes, formal clothes, a uniform of some kind, or a space suit.  There's no specific emotional meaning hidden in the phrase.  I'm just simply wearing some type of clothing.

If I turn the phrase around and I said I was going to wear clothing of a particular type, then I'm putting emphasis on the word "particular" and depending on my facial expression my listener would be able to see that there's something that I especially like or dislike about the clothes.  You might even hear the speaker draw out and enunciate each syllable of the word particular separately to give it emphasis.

The phrase is also often combined with sarcasm.  "I just LOVE clothes of that par-TIC-ular type," she said of the small piece of sparkly fabric that was supposed to cover her somehow.